# vim: mapping several commands to one shortcut

Tags: key-bindings

This does NOT work with files opened in several tabs (put in `~/.vimrc` obviously):

```
noremap <F5> :wa<CR> <bar> :!global_stack_build_run.sh<CR>
```

Neither it works when I use `|` instead of `<bar>`.

It appears to run only `:wa`.

Comment: Are you sure this does not work? According to the documentation [`:help map_bar`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map_bar) using `<bar>` should work. A simple mapping did just work. Try removing the `<cr>` from your mapping and see if it will be put into the command line

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thank you! Indeed removing `<cr>` after `wa:` worked: `noremap <F5> :wa <bar> :!global_stack_build_run.sh<CR>`. Consider it an answer.

Comment: You dont’t need the second colon in the version in your comment

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, if you care, you can copy your comment into the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [`:help map_bar`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map_bar) using  should work. A simple mapping I tried did just work. So try removing the `<cr>` from your mapping and see if it will be put into the command line